# OpenZFS on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: zfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Has anybody seen or tried running OpenZFS under Windows Subsystem for Linux?

I know that someone is working on a [windows port of OpenZFS](https://phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OpenZFS-Windows), but it would seem that using the Linux port would be much more stable direction to start with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Subsystem for Linux allows running Linux *user-space* programs on Windows. ZFS driver for Linux is implemented as Linux *kernel* module, which you can't use with NT kernel.

Also, WSL does not presently implement FUSE so that method is also not available.

Comment: How about as a FUSE module. Can they be run under WSFL?  From Ubuntu wiki "The ZFS filesystem is available for Ubuntu as either a FUSE module or a native kernel module."

Comment: I'm not aware that WSL implements FUSE.